# lapply for list comparisons in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

My first 3 lines of R code below work fine. But when I make these 3 lines into a function,  I get the `Error in m[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Can this be fixed?

```
m1 <- lm(hp ~ vs, mtcars)
m2 <- lm(hp ~ vs*wt, mtcars)

pchisq(2 * (logLik(m2) - logLik(m1)), df = abs(m1$df.residual - m2$df.residual), lower = F)

###### Make a function of above 3 lines: ######

 compare <- function(...){

   m <- list(...)
   L <- length(m)

lapply(1:L, function(i) pchisq(2 * (logLik(m[[i+1]]) - logLik(m[[i]])), df = abs(m[[i]]$df.residual - m[[i+1]]$df.residual), lower = F) )
 }
 ## Example of use:
  compare(m1, m2)       # `Error in m[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds`
```

Comment: You `lapply` from 1 to the length of the list (2), but then you have `i+1` in the function so it fails because there's no 3rd element of the list. You could change your `lapply` to be over `1:(L-1)`, but I don't think this will extend to a list of 3 models

Comment: It would depend on how you structured your list of inputs and which comparisons you want to make, since the models have to be nested to run the likelihood ratio test. One option would be to hard code `m[[1]]` for the simplest model, and then if every other list element was a more complex model that function would do a likelihood ratio test for each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lapply statement is going from the first index (1) to the last index of `m` (`L`, in this case).  So, when you try to call `m[[i+1]]`, you're calling an index that is not part of `m`.  If `m` has a length of 5, then you're call `m[[5+1]]`, which is out of bounds.